# Reading in an unknown size matrix from txt file in C

Tags: c, matrix

I'm having problems reading in an unknown size array from a txt file in C. The txt file contains values separated by spaces, and rows start every new line. For example:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

My problem is that I can "hardcode" something like for i, j =100000 and read in a matrix assuming 100000 is a big enough number. But this is not efficient. Is there a way I can create a matrix big enough and scan in these values into a 2d array?

Comment: is it a square matrix ? If it is, may be u can count num of elements in first line and u will get the idea of size of matrix.

Comment: I used while(fscanf(fin,"%f",&column)!='\n'){column++;}

Comment: I guess fscanf returns number of items successfully read.

Comment: Is there a way I can only read the first line of numbers? The !='\n' is not working. If I can find how many numbers are in the first row I can do the rest.

Comment: Thats still hardcoding, how do I know how big line should be...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each row will contain the same number of columns (should be a requirement for a proper matrix), you should pre-scan the file - just reading the first line.  See how many columns it has, then create a sized 2D array that can be populated from an actual read of the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Use linked lists. Just manually allocate memory while your input from text file is valid. I'd suggest using two int type variables to track your column and row count so you could later easily find entries if you need them by coordinates in your matrix.

Basically you will have a one dimensional array, but you will know that in reality it is two dimensional. Two variables I mentioned earlier will serve so you would know actual dimension of your matrix.

Element you will try to find with coordinates x and y will be located at index:

```
y * columnCount + x
```

To learn how the linked lists work please read this:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html